# Changing a Control's property via a delegate

Tags: vb.net

First off, pardon me if my English is bad, I'm not a native English speaker.

I'm fairly new to programming and I'm trying to teach myself VB.NET
I came across a problem while trying to learn about Delegates. (see code below)

What I'm trying to accomplish is to update a specified Control's text property via a thread. However, as soon as I start the thread, I get an ArgumentException Error. I have completely no idea what's wrong. Anybody have an idea what i've done wrong here?

```
Public Class Form1

Delegate Sub myDelegate1(ByVal s_Name As Control, ByVal s_txt As String)
Public txtUpdate As New myDelegate1(AddressOf upd_ControlTextProperty)

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Label1.Text = vbnullstring
End Sub

Private Sub upd_ControlTextProperty(ByVal ControlName As Control, ByVal txt As String)
    ControlName.Text = txt
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim thread1 As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf threadstart)
    thread1.IsBackground = True
    thread1.Start()

End Sub

Private Sub threadstart()
        Me.Invoke(Me.txtUpdate, New Object(), {Label1, "This is Label 1"})
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: You're passing 3 arguments, but the callback is expecting only 2.

Comment: hhmmm..This confuses me, an example from msdn [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1hetckb(v=vs.110).aspx) passes 3 arguments as well but the callback is expecting only 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As TheValyreanGroup said, your delegate is supposed to accept two arguments, and you pass it three :

```
Me.Invoke(Me.txtUpdate, New Object(), {Label1, "This is Label 1"})
          ^-1--------^  ^-2--------^  ^-3-----------------------^
```

So just remove the `New Object()` thing, and transform this `{Label1, ...}` into just a string :

```
Me.Invoke(Me.txtUpdate, "This is Label 1")
```

OK Better that way.

On a second hand, what you are doing is not very usefull.

- You create a new Thread from your UI Thread.
- With this new Thread, you invoke back the UI Thread and you stop your Thread...

Remember that a Control can be updated only by the Thread who created the Form (the UI thread).

Unless you have a good reason to work with your background thread, you can resume your code to :

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Label1.Text = vbnullstring
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Label1.Text = "This is Label 1"
End Sub

End Class
```

**UPDATE**
(from comments)

To make it more clear, here is a schema (that I took on https://androidkennel.org/android-networking-tutorial-with-asynctask/, if any restrictions apply I will remove the image)

[image: UI Thread and Background Thread]

The Main UI Thread is used for things :

- React to user events (clicks, inputs...) and start background threads that will do the process
- Update the User Interface when the background thread is over or during the task.

When I say what you're doing is not usefull is because your background thread does not do any processing, it just signals the UI thread to update the UI...

Comment: Hey thanks man! I understand that it is simpler to update the control's property with the button click event or from the Form itself. This was just an exercise for me to understand and apply delegates. On another note though, why do say creating a new thread from the UI thread not useful? I mean, where should threads be created? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: There is no problem starting a new thread from the UI thread. The issue is more with the purpose of the new thread which is designed to run 2 asynchronous processes simultaneously. If the main purpose of the new thread is to update the UI then there are going to be continuous callbacks to the UI thread to perform the update. Running such an operation on a second thread is therefore not optimal as the UI updates can be taken care of by a single UI thread.

Comment: @printf updated my answer so you may have a clearer understanding for the use of Background threads

Answer (score 0):

I would try this approach. upd_ControlTextProperty can be called successfully either from the UI thread or your new thread.

```
Public Class Form1

Delegate Sub myDelegate1(ByVal s_Name As Control, ByVal s_txt As String)
Public txtUpdate As New myDelegate1(AddressOf upd_ControlTextProperty)

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Label1.Text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub upd_ControlTextProperty(ByVal ControlName As Control, ByVal txt As String)
    If Me.InvokeRequired = True Then
        Me.Invoke(txtUpdate, New Object() {ControlName, txt})
    Else
        ControlName.Text = txt
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim thread1 As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf threadstart)
    thread1.IsBackground = True
    thread1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub threadstart()
    upd_ControlTextProperty(Label1, "This is Label 1")
End Sub

End Class
```